# Django AttributeError: 'Cart' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error on my django project:

```
   Request Method: GET
   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/
   Exception Type: AttributeError at /cart/
   Exception Value: 'Cart' object has no attribute 'get'
```

and here is carts.views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from store.models import Product
from .models import Cart, CartItem



# Create your views here.

def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart

def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)
            )
        cart.save()
    
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product= product,
            quantity= 1,
            cart= cart,
        )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart')


def cart(request):
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html')
```

### I tried:

1. rewrite the name of class 'Cart'
2. use objectDoesnotexist instead of DoesnotExit
3. double check the names of the classes in models.py

I am not able to debug this error. I overlooked my codes many times, but cant able to understand where is the error being generated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from store.models import Product

# Create your models here.

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id         = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    date_added      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id

class CartItem(models.Model):
    product         = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart            = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cart')
    quantity        = models.IntegerField()
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

Edit:
Full Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/

Django Version: 3.2.3
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'category',
 'accounts',
 'store',
 'carts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\greatkart\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\greatkart\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "D:\greatkart\env\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cart/
Exception Value: 'Cart' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Edit :
urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Cart, name='cart'),
    path('add_cart/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
]
```

---

Comment: Paste the Cart model

Comment: And please paste the actual exception tracelog.

Comment: You should consider using `get_or_create`. That would reduce the length of this view by at least half its size. Also the log indicates you're sending a GET request, but I am not sure to understand, if this view is supposed to create in the first place, use a POST request.

Comment: Please show us full traceback error.

Comment: models.py has been added.

Comment: Full traceback added.

Comment: @asdfasdf please show your url patterns, the error suggests that instead of a response your view is returning a `Cart` instance?

Comment: urls.py has been added

Comment: @asdfasdf In `path('', views.Cart, name='cart'),` did you mean to write `views.cart` instead of `views.Cart`? (Note the capitalization, `Cart` is your model name and `cart` is the name of your view)...

Comment: You are right Abdul Aziz Barakat. It works. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Abdul Aziz Barakat:

@asdfasdf In `path('', views.Cart, name='cart')`, did you mean to write `views.cart` instead of `views.Cart`? (Note the capitalization, `Cart` is your model name and `cart` is the name of your view)... – Abdul Aziz Barkat 6 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

I started using the ["Model.objects.filter().first()"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) instead of the "Model.objects.get()"
because of those errors.

You could try this:

```
 cart = Cart.objects.filter(cart_id=_cart_id(request).first()

 if not cart:
     new_cart = Cart(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
     new_cart.save()
```

This method gives you all objects with the correct "cart_id".
With ".first()" you will convert the giving queryset into one object (You need to do this even if you just have one object in the querset)

Instead of this

```
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)
            )
        cart.save()
```